# After Expo Eject, run-android error: spawnSync gradlew.bat Enoent

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I was using expo, but then needed to link a third party package so I ejected from expo with Expo Kit. now when i try `react-native run-android`, the metro bundler starts but then the following error occurs:

```
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error spawnSync gradlew.bat ENOENT
debug Error: spawnSync gradlew.bat ENOENT
    at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:981:20)
    at spawnSync (child_process.js:585:24)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:613:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Mahmoud's Laptop\RN\ikraawarka\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:58:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Mahmoud's Laptop\RN\ikraawarka\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:142:41)
    at then.result (C:\Users\Mahmoud's Laptop\RN\ikraawarka\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:104:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

more info:
`react-native-cli: 2.0.1`
`react-native: 0.59.8`
`expo: 2.20.2`

I'm still able to run expo start and it works in the expo client app. Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised, no one had helped. Mar 2020 still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: yup, i don't even remember what i did back then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you guys ejected to expo kit simply `expo start` on your project directory and run the project in your Android Studio or XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have the same problem as I did, where `android/gradlew.bat` was not found.
I don't know when it disappeared...
To solve it you can copy this file from another project.

Comment: Hmm, honestly I forgot how I fixed it as it was a long time ago, let's keep this here hoping it helps others